# "Must declare the scalar variable @dni"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm kinda new to C# and I cannot understand why is it throwing the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable `@dni`

There's no problem when building the project, but when I run the application and reach a certain view, after I insert the values and hit the 'continue' button it shows the said error

```
var command = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO [POLICHICHI].Usuarios(dni,nombre,apellido,direccion,telefono,fechaNacimiento,idRol)" +
                    "VALUES (@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@direccion,@telefono,@fechaNacimiento,2);" +
                    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
                    transaccion.Connection);

command.Transaction = transaccion;
command.Parameters.Add("@dni", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox3.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@apellido", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox6.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@direccion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox4.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@fechaNacimiento", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 3).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
```

Although I'm not sure, I would think that both `@dni` and `@telefono` could be causing troubles.

EDIT: here´s the full event

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var transaccion = Program.conexion().BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                if (estaVacio(textBox1.Text) || estaVacio(textBox2.Text) || estaVacio(textBox3.Text) || estaVacio(textBox4.Text))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Debe llenar los campos obligatorios");
                }

                if (!contieneSoloNumeros(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    throw new Exception("El dni debe estar compuesto solo por numeros");
                }

                // Hay que hacer un if aca, porque es insert si es la primera vez o Update si ya compro alguna vez
                var command4 = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO [POLICHICHI].Usuarios(dni,nombre,apellido,direccion,telefono,fechaNacimiento,idRol) " +
                    "VALUES (@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@direccion,@telefono,@fechaNacimiento,2); " +
                    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
                    transaccion.Connection);

                command4.Transaction = transaccion;
                command4.Parameters.Add("@dni", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = 33;//Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                command4.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox3.Text;
                command4.Parameters.Add("@apellido", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox6.Text;
                command4.Parameters.Add("@direccion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = textBox4.Text;
                command4.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4333; //Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                command4.Parameters.Add("@fechaNacimiento", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 3).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
                 //       2- ¿Que poner en los campos username y password? Supuestamente los tendria que tener al principio cuando se logea

                var idUsuario = command4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                command4.Transaction = transaccion;
                command4.Parameters.Clear();
                command4.Parameters.Add("@idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idUsuario;

                command4.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaccion.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception excepcion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excepcion.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            if (!estaVacio(textBox1.Text) || !estaVacio(textBox2.Text) || !estaVacio(textBox3.Text) || !estaVacio(textBox4.Text))
            {
                if (contieneSoloNumeros(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    using (Form generarReserva = new CompraReservaPasaje.generarReserva())
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        generarReserva.ShowDialog();
                        this.Show();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @RufusL Please do not make functional changes to the OP's code to make it fit on one line. Only whitespace is okay.

Comment: @GSerg Ok. Was trying to remove horizontal scrolling, and I didn't think the concatenation was a functional change, but I see what you mean.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Side note: you probably want dateTimePicker1.Value, not Text.  Usually, telephone numbers aren't treated as integers.

Comment: @RufusL the error is happening in the line `command.Parameters.Add("@dni", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

I´ve also discovered that if I commented that line and remove the variable @dni from the query, I have the same error but with the next line and variable (which is @nombre)

This is quite odd, because I´ve already used this type of function in other view´s query, but in that case it was a SQL and this one is a T-SQL, maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: try command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dni", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)).Value

Comment: @Mav nope, still the same error.

Comment: I kept changing things and now I think that the problem could be not in the comman.Parameters, but in the insert query itself. i.e. if I remove @dni ONLY from the line `"VALUES (@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@direccion,@telefono,@fechaNacimiento,2);" +`

the error is now in the next variable, which is @nombre

Comment: @Juani, the code worked for me so I am curious why this is happening. I used the exact same snippet but instead of textboxes I used hardcoded values of respective types.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich well, that´s good to hear I guess? I swear I tried using hardcoded values, but still the same problem

Comment: @Juani could you please post entire call stack?

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich there, I posted the full event of the button

Comment: Could you please specify the framework version and environment you are running this code on? Still unable to reproduce.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich sure thing, the are .NET Framework 4.5 and I run it on Visual Studio Express 2012

Comment: What is this `command4.Parameters.Clear(); command4.Parameters.Add("@idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idUsuario; command4.ExecuteNonQuery();` supposed to do? You are executing the same insert statement but only with one parameter, hence missing variable errors.

Comment: @Alex yeah, you could be right. What should I do? I don´t quite fully understand how to work with `command` and it´s giving me headaches.

To answer your question, @idUsuario references the PK from the table "Users" and a friend told me i should do something like that when working with an identity value, to get the next available PK for the new user

Comment: In your case PK (dUsuario) seems to be an auto incrementing identity. (Did you create it?) Once you get the value back using `var idUsuario = command4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`  you can pass it as FK to related tables if needed. To fix your code: Delete the lines mentioned in my previous post; they don't make any sense (to me anyway).

Comment: @Alex IT WORKED!!! Alex, I can´t thank you enough, I´ve been struggling with this for a long time and you saved me. Thank you and everyone who tried to help out

Answer (score 0):

In these comments @Alex helped me solve the problem I was having

["Must declare the scalar variable @dni"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762726/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-dni#comment100084557_56762726)

["Must declare the scalar variable @dni"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762726/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-dni#comment100084857_56762726)